Converting Date Timestamp from UTC to EST without the Timezone in Athena
I am trying to convert a datetimestamp column from UTC to EST without the output including the timezone, and also CAST it as a timestamp.
I have tried the below, but the resulting column of the query is still in UTC and not EST.
    CAST(at_timezone(datetimestamp_column,'US/Eastern') AS timestamp)
    CAST(datetimestamp_column AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern' AS timestamp)


"but it keeps the datetimestamp_column as UTC"  - can you please elaborate? How do you check that? Do you mean the resulting column of the SELECT?

@GuruStron Yes, the resulting column is still in UTC and not EST.

Here's how you can convert between timezones in Athena:
SELECT at_timezone(with_timezone(TIMESTAMP '2022-11-01 09:08:07.321', 'UTC'), 'US/Eastern')
This returns 2022-11-01 05:08:07.321 US/Eastern

How would we exclude the time zone in our output?
I hope to return 2022-11-01 05:08:07.321 without the timezone at the end

You can do
SELECT date_format(at_timezone(with_timezone(TIMESTAMP '2022-11-01 09:08:07.321', 'UTC'), 'US/Eastern'), '%Y-%i-%d %H:%i:%s') to format the result as string.

In case you need the result as timestamp but without the time zone I think the only way is
SELECT date_parse(date_format(at_timezone(with_timezone(TIMESTAMP '2022-11-01 09:08:07.321', 'UTC'), 'US/Eastern'), '%Y-%i-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%i-%d %H:%i:%s') but I wouldn't advise to do that as it's potentially destructive
